# Looping through product of a specific category

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get all products with a specific category. It shows the data if I remove the product category code from the code else doesn't show anything. I am sure I am using the right product category.

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'men'
    ),
),
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
  while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    $post_query->the_post();

    $tre = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_xoo-wl-users', true );

    $data = json_decode($tre);

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key;
        echo "<br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should see this guide as it mentions to use hide_empty if nothing is showing (just in case!) https://wpza.net/woocommerce/how-to-loop-through-woocommerce-categories/

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in `$args` so it will display products only of `men` category

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'product_cat' => 'men', 'orderby' => 'date' ); ?>
```

Comment: Doesnt display anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'men', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>           
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">
                            <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                        </a>

                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The reference here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67247/how-to-display-product-specific-to-a-category-with-woocommerce-plugin

Comment: Doesnt display anything